# How to send a same parameter with different value from controller to model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to sent a parameter from controller to model. Then, the parameter will be processed in the model. But, the parameter name is should be the same. How to do this?

```
$thumb_ass     = $this->MProperty->sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,$par = "PAR_1");
$slide_ass     = $this->MProperty->sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,$par = "PAR_2");

$data          = array ('thumb_ass' => $thumb_ass, 'slide_ass' =>$slide_ass);
```

But the parameter is not sent to model.

Comment: Whats wrong with this code? Can you better explain what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, the name you're a binding controller to model. All you need is placement.

**Example**

```
$this->myFunction("Is this works ?", "Are You Sure ?");

function myFunction($var1, $var2){
    echo $var1; # prints - Is this works ?
    echo $var2; # prints - Are You Sure ?
}
```

---

As per your question you have `sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,$par = "PAR_1")` and `sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,$par = "PAR_2")`. You can do same aproch what I mention

```
sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,"PAR_2") or sel_asset_by_list($val_id_assets,$par = "PAR_2")
```

In model function all, you need is two variables only

```
function sel_asset_by_list($id,$par)
{
    echo $id;
    echo $par; # prints - PAR_1 or PAR_2
}
```

**AND** there is two different value in `$par`, so you can use [**Switch Case**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp) or [**Else-if**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp) to get data based on your value